# What is Ubuntu silo?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, development

There is this Ubuntu silo installer at the uAppStore, it has very positive ratings, like "I wish I would know about it earlier". It looks like some kind of testing suite? I tried to Google it, but there is no exact info what it is. In my research I came across [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1605919), urging that it is dangerous to provide the app in the main store.

What is this silo thing? How does it work, how can it damage the system, and how can it be useful?